# javascript validation with an array

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp, validation

I wrote a javascript function to validate that the user input data is not empty. The function called "isNotEmpty()" identifies that the text box is empty. But however the main function returns a true statement to the JSP page. Thus the form gets submitted.

The alert no 2&3 fires according the input from the form. but the Alert No1 dose not fires in any circumstances.

Please check on this and assist me.
Thank you.

```
var firstName;
var data  = new Array(); 

function formEntryValidationTest() {
    firstName = document.forms["regForm"]["firstName"];
    data[0] = isNotEmpty(firstName);//check the first name is empty

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        if(data[i]=="false")
        {
            alert("Check"); //alert No-1
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// this is the function to check whether the input is not empty
function isNotEmpty(obj) {
    if(obj.value!="") {
        alert("true"); //alert No-2
        return "true";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("false");//alert No-3
        return "false";
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me: http://jsbin.com/ozalan/1/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're returning the string `"false"` rather than the boolean value `false`, which in JavaScript evaluates to a "truthy" value.

Change the return statements in `isNotEmpty` to `return true;` and `return false;` and the condition in `formEntryValidationTest` to `if (!data[i])`.

Also, the condition you check in `isNotEmpty` is too strict. It will return true for `undefined` and `null`, which may be the reason your code isn't working. Change it to something like this:

```
function isNotEmpty(value){
  return value ? value.length > 0 : false;
}
```

Then pass the input value directly rather than passing the input object itself:

```
data[0] = isNotEmpty(firstName.value);
```

Comment: No generally in the form onSubmit, I calls the formEntryValidationTest() function.

Comment: I changed the source code according to your instructions, no improvement.

Comment: I found a clue. When I commented the "data[0] = isNotEmpty(firstName.value)" and changed the condition as "if(!isNotEmpty(firstName.value))", it worked perfectly. Meanwhile I taken-off the comment which I mentioned here same problem occurred. Can you say why is it?

Comment: Here are my files. You'll find error even I made the changes according your instructions. I don't know why. Please refer the link

http://www.mediafire.com/?9kac6352z6749z0

Answer (score 1):

You are using strings "true" and "false" instead of boolean values true and false. Remove the quotes as in:

```
   return true

instead of 

   return "true"
```

Do the same in your if statement:

```
    if(data[i]==false)
instead of
    if(data[i]=="false")
```

(Note that there are no quotes)

Comment: I did but the issue remains same.